# How to get and compare substring in java script?

Tags: javascript

May be stupid Q for you. 
I am getting URL by using document.URL

Now i want to check whether that URL contain my input string or not.

Is ther any way to do this or I have to go for manual process.?

would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to check. `document.URL` is a `String`, so you can use for example:

```
 //use indexof
 document.URL.indexOf('this is my input string') > -1;

 //use the String.search method (equivalent to indexOf)
 document.URL.search('this is my input string') > -1

 //use a regular expression with method 'test'
 /this is my input string/i.test(document.URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf() Method to return the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

Or, use search() Method with a regular expression. Which is much more powerful.

Check the info in w3school:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp